# How does scipy.linalg.eigvals actually calculate eigenvalues?

Tags: numpy, scipy, eigenvalue

I can't find any documentation on how this thing actually calculates eigenvalues, the documentation just says it uses '_geev LAPACK routines', but I have searched and searched for documentation on that and can't find it either. Getting weird links to intel websites which furthermore make my search in vain. Any help would be appreciated thx.

Comment: The algorithms are described in [LAPACK guide](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node5.html).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your [LAPACK-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK). Therefore there are multiple candidates and Intel's MKL is one of them.

The original LAPACK (probably not much in use; but i'm only guessing here) is quite nice as open-source (Fortran) and well-documented.

Here is the double-version (see the `D`-prefix) from [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/dgeev.f.html):

```
SUBROUTINE DGEEV( JOBVL, JOBVR, N, A, LDA, WR, WI, VL, LDVL, VR,
$                  LDVR, WORK, LWORK, INFO )
*
*  -- LAPACK driver routine (version 3.1) --
*     Univ. of Tennessee, Univ. of California Berkeley and NAG Ltd..
*     November 2006
*
*     .. Scalar Arguments ..
CHARACTER          JOBVL, JOBVR
INTEGER            INFO, LDA, LDVL, LDVR, LWORK, N
*     ..
*     .. Array Arguments ..
DOUBLE PRECISION   A( LDA, * ), VL( LDVL, * ), VR( LDVR, * ),
$                   WI( * ), WORK( * ), WR( * )
*     ..
*
*  Purpose
*  =======
*
*  DGEEV computes for an N-by-N real nonsymmetric matrix A, the
*  eigenvalues and, optionally, the left and/or right eigenvectors.
*
*  The right eigenvector v(j) of A satisfies
*                   A * v(j) = lambda(j) * v(j)
*  where lambda(j) is its eigenvalue.
*  The left eigenvector u(j) of A satisfies
*                u(j)**H * A = lambda(j) * u(j)**H
*  where u(j)**H denotes the conjugate transpose of u(j).
*
*  The computed eigenvectors are normalized to have Euclidean norm
*  equal to 1 and largest component real.
*
*  Arguments
*  =========
*
*  JOBVL   (input) CHARACTER*1
*          = 'N': left eigenvectors of A are not computed;
*          = 'V': left eigenvectors of A are computed.
*
*  JOBVR   (input) CHARACTER*1
*          = 'N': right eigenvectors of A are not computed;
*          = 'V': right eigenvectors of A are computed.
*
*  N       (input) INTEGER
*          The order of the matrix A. N >= 0.
*
*  A       (input/output) DOUBLE PRECISION array, dimension (LDA,N)
*          On entry, the N-by-N matrix A.
*          On exit, A has been overwritten.
*
*  LDA     (input) INTEGER
*          The leading dimension of the array A.  LDA >= max(1,N).
*
*  WR      (output) DOUBLE PRECISION array, dimension (N)
*  WI      (output) DOUBLE PRECISION array, dimension (N)
*          WR and WI contain the real and imaginary parts,
*          respectively, of the computed eigenvalues.  Complex
*          conjugate pairs of eigenvalues appear consecutively
*          with the eigenvalue having the positive imaginary part
*          first.
*
*  VL      (output) DOUBLE PRECISION array, dimension (LDVL,N)
*          If JOBVL = 'V', the left eigenvectors u(j) are stored one
*          after another in the columns of VL, in the same order
*          as their eigenvalues.
*          If JOBVL = 'N', VL is not referenced.
*          If the j-th eigenvalue is real, then u(j) = VL(:,j),
*          the j-th column of VL.
*          If the j-th and (j+1)-st eigenvalues form a complex
*          conjugate pair, then u(j) = VL(:,j) + i*VL(:,j+1) and
*          u(j+1) = VL(:,j) - i*VL(:,j+1).
*
*  LDVL    (input) INTEGER
*          The leading dimension of the array VL.  LDVL >= 1; if
*          JOBVL = 'V', LDVL >= N.
*
*  VR      (output) DOUBLE PRECISION array, dimension (LDVR,N)
*          If JOBVR = 'V', the right eigenvectors v(j) are stored one
*          after another in the columns of VR, in the same order
*          as their eigenvalues.
*          If JOBVR = 'N', VR is not referenced.
*          If the j-th eigenvalue is real, then v(j) = VR(:,j),
*          the j-th column of VR.
*          If the j-th and (j+1)-st eigenvalues form a complex
*          conjugate pair, then v(j) = VR(:,j) + i*VR(:,j+1) and
*          v(j+1) = VR(:,j) - i*VR(:,j+1).
*
*  LDVR    (input) INTEGER
*          The leading dimension of the array VR.  LDVR >= 1; if
*          JOBVR = 'V', LDVR >= N.
*
*  WORK    (workspace/output) DOUBLE PRECISION array, dimension (MAX(1,LWORK))
*          On exit, if INFO = 0, WORK(1) returns the optimal LWORK.
*
*  LWORK   (input) INTEGER
*          The dimension of the array WORK.  LWORK >= max(1,3*N), and
*          if JOBVL = 'V' or JOBVR = 'V', LWORK >= 4*N.  For good
*          performance, LWORK must generally be larger.
*
*          If LWORK = -1, then a workspace query is assumed; the routine
*          only calculates the optimal size of the WORK array, returns
*          this value as the first entry of the WORK array, and no error
*          message related to LWORK is issued by XERBLA.
*
*  INFO    (output) INTEGER
*          = 0:  successful exit
*          < 0:  if INFO = -i, the i-th argument had an illegal value.
*          > 0:  if INFO = i, the QR algorithm failed to compute all the
*                eigenvalues, and no eigenvectors have been computed;
*                elements i+1:N of WR and WI contain eigenvalues which
*                have converged.
*
*  =====================================================================
*
*     .. Parameters ..
DOUBLE PRECISION   ZERO, ONE
PARAMETER          ( ZERO = 0.0D0, ONE = 1.0D0 )
*     ..
*     .. Local Scalars ..
LOGICAL            LQUERY, SCALEA, WANTVL, WANTVR
CHARACTER          SIDE
INTEGER            HSWORK, I, IBAL, IERR, IHI, ILO, ITAU, IWRK, K,
$                   MAXWRK, MINWRK, NOUT
DOUBLE PRECISION   ANRM, BIGNUM, CS, CSCALE, EPS, R, SCL, SMLNUM,
$                   SN
*     ..
*     .. Local Arrays ..
LOGICAL            SELECT( 1 )
DOUBLE PRECISION   DUM( 1 )
*     ..
*     .. External Subroutines ..
EXTERNAL           DGEBAK, DGEBAL, DGEHRD, DHSEQR, DLABAD, DLACPY,
$                   DLARTG, DLASCL, DORGHR, DROT, DSCAL, DTREVC,
$                   XERBLA
*     ..
*     .. External Functions ..
LOGICAL            LSAME
INTEGER            IDAMAX, ILAENV
DOUBLE PRECISION   DLAMCH, DLANGE, DLAPY2, DNRM2
EXTERNAL           LSAME, IDAMAX, ILAENV, DLAMCH, DLANGE, DLAPY2,
$                   DNRM2
*     ..
*     .. Intrinsic Functions ..
INTRINSIC          MAX, SQRT
*     ..
*     .. Executable Statements ..
*
*     Test the input arguments
*
INFO = 0
LQUERY = ( LWORK.EQ.-1 )
WANTVL = LSAME( JOBVL, 'V' )
WANTVR = LSAME( JOBVR, 'V' )
IF( ( .NOT.WANTVL ) .AND. ( .NOT.LSAME( JOBVL, 'N' ) ) ) THEN
   INFO = -1
ELSE IF( ( .NOT.WANTVR ) .AND. ( .NOT.LSAME( JOBVR, 'N' ) ) ) THEN
   INFO = -2
ELSE IF( N.LT.0 ) THEN
   INFO = -3
ELSE IF( LDA.LT.MAX( 1, N ) ) THEN
   INFO = -5
ELSE IF( LDVL.LT.1 .OR. ( WANTVL .AND. LDVL.LT.N ) ) THEN
   INFO = -9
ELSE IF( LDVR.LT.1 .OR. ( WANTVR .AND. LDVR.LT.N ) ) THEN
   INFO = -11
END IF
*
*     Compute workspace
*      (Note: Comments in the code beginning "Workspace:" describe the
*       minimal amount of workspace needed at that point in the code,
*       as well as the preferred amount for good performance.
*       NB refers to the optimal block size for the immediately
*       following subroutine, as returned by ILAENV.
*       HSWORK refers to the workspace preferred by DHSEQR, as
*       calculated below. HSWORK is computed assuming ILO=1 and IHI=N,
*       the worst case.)
*
IF( INFO.EQ.0 ) THEN
   IF( N.EQ.0 ) THEN
      MINWRK = 1
      MAXWRK = 1
   ELSE
      MAXWRK = 2*N + N*ILAENV( 1, 'DGEHRD', ' ', N, 1, N, 0 )
      IF( WANTVL ) THEN
         MINWRK = 4*N
         MAXWRK = MAX( MAXWRK, 2*N + ( N - 1 )*ILAENV( 1,
$                       'DORGHR', ' ', N, 1, N, -1 ) )
         CALL DHSEQR( 'S', 'V', N, 1, N, A, LDA, WR, WI, VL, LDVL,
$                WORK, -1, INFO )
         HSWORK = WORK( 1 )
         MAXWRK = MAX( MAXWRK, N + 1, N + HSWORK )
         MAXWRK = MAX( MAXWRK, 4*N )
      ELSE IF( WANTVR ) THEN
         MINWRK = 4*N
         MAXWRK = MAX( MAXWRK, 2*N + ( N - 1 )*ILAENV( 1,
$                       'DORGHR', ' ', N, 1, N, -1 ) )
         CALL DHSEQR( 'S', 'V', N, 1, N, A, LDA, WR, WI, VR, LDVR,
$                WORK, -1, INFO )
         HSWORK = WORK( 1 )
         MAXWRK = MAX( MAXWRK, N + 1, N + HSWORK )
         MAXWRK = MAX( MAXWRK, 4*N )
      ELSE 
         MINWRK = 3*N
         CALL DHSEQR( 'E', 'N', N, 1, N, A, LDA, WR, WI, VR, LDVR,
$                WORK, -1, INFO )
         HSWORK = WORK( 1 )
         MAXWRK = MAX( MAXWRK, N + 1, N + HSWORK )
      END IF
      MAXWRK = MAX( MAXWRK, MINWRK )
   END IF
   WORK( 1 ) = MAXWRK
*
   IF( LWORK.LT.MINWRK .AND. .NOT.LQUERY ) THEN
      INFO = -13
   END IF
END IF
*
IF( INFO.NE.0 ) THEN
   CALL XERBLA( 'DGEEV ', -INFO )
   RETURN
ELSE IF( LQUERY ) THEN
   RETURN
END IF
*
*     Quick return if possible
*
IF( N.EQ.0 )
$   RETURN
*
*     Get machine constants
*
EPS = DLAMCH( 'P' )
SMLNUM = DLAMCH( 'S' )
BIGNUM = ONE / SMLNUM
CALL DLABAD( SMLNUM, BIGNUM )
SMLNUM = SQRT( SMLNUM ) / EPS
BIGNUM = ONE / SMLNUM
*
*     Scale A if max element outside range [SMLNUM,BIGNUM]
*
ANRM = DLANGE( 'M', N, N, A, LDA, DUM )
SCALEA = .FALSE.
IF( ANRM.GT.ZERO .AND. ANRM.LT.SMLNUM ) THEN
   SCALEA = .TRUE.
   CSCALE = SMLNUM
ELSE IF( ANRM.GT.BIGNUM ) THEN
   SCALEA = .TRUE.
   CSCALE = BIGNUM
END IF
IF( SCALEA )
$   CALL DLASCL( 'G', 0, 0, ANRM, CSCALE, N, N, A, LDA, IERR )
*
*     Balance the matrix
*     (Workspace: need N)
*
IBAL = 1
CALL DGEBAL( 'B', N, A, LDA, ILO, IHI, WORK( IBAL ), IERR )
*
*     Reduce to upper Hessenberg form
*     (Workspace: need 3*N, prefer 2*N+N*NB)
*
ITAU = IBAL + N
IWRK = ITAU + N
CALL DGEHRD( N, ILO, IHI, A, LDA, WORK( ITAU ), WORK( IWRK ),
$             LWORK-IWRK+1, IERR )
*
IF( WANTVL ) THEN
*
*        Want left eigenvectors
*        Copy Householder vectors to VL
*
   SIDE = 'L'
   CALL DLACPY( 'L', N, N, A, LDA, VL, LDVL )
*
*        Generate orthogonal matrix in VL
*        (Workspace: need 3*N-1, prefer 2*N+(N-1)*NB)
*
   CALL DORGHR( N, ILO, IHI, VL, LDVL, WORK( ITAU ), WORK( IWRK ),
$                LWORK-IWRK+1, IERR )
*
*        Perform QR iteration, accumulating Schur vectors in VL
*        (Workspace: need N+1, prefer N+HSWORK (see comments) )
*
   IWRK = ITAU
   CALL DHSEQR( 'S', 'V', N, ILO, IHI, A, LDA, WR, WI, VL, LDVL,
$                WORK( IWRK ), LWORK-IWRK+1, INFO )
*
   IF( WANTVR ) THEN
*
*           Want left and right eigenvectors
*           Copy Schur vectors to VR
*
      SIDE = 'B'
      CALL DLACPY( 'F', N, N, VL, LDVL, VR, LDVR )
   END IF
*
ELSE IF( WANTVR ) THEN
*
*        Want right eigenvectors
*        Copy Householder vectors to VR
*
   SIDE = 'R'
   CALL DLACPY( 'L', N, N, A, LDA, VR, LDVR )
*
*        Generate orthogonal matrix in VR
*        (Workspace: need 3*N-1, prefer 2*N+(N-1)*NB)
*
   CALL DORGHR( N, ILO, IHI, VR, LDVR, WORK( ITAU ), WORK( IWRK ),
$                LWORK-IWRK+1, IERR )
*
*        Perform QR iteration, accumulating Schur vectors in VR
*        (Workspace: need N+1, prefer N+HSWORK (see comments) )
*
   IWRK = ITAU
   CALL DHSEQR( 'S', 'V', N, ILO, IHI, A, LDA, WR, WI, VR, LDVR,
$                WORK( IWRK ), LWORK-IWRK+1, INFO )
*
ELSE
*
*        Compute eigenvalues only
*        (Workspace: need N+1, prefer N+HSWORK (see comments) )
*
   IWRK = ITAU
   CALL DHSEQR( 'E', 'N', N, ILO, IHI, A, LDA, WR, WI, VR, LDVR,
$                WORK( IWRK ), LWORK-IWRK+1, INFO )
END IF
*
*     If INFO > 0 from DHSEQR, then quit
*
IF( INFO.GT.0 )
$   GO TO 50
*
IF( WANTVL .OR. WANTVR ) THEN
*
*        Compute left and/or right eigenvectors
*        (Workspace: need 4*N)
*
   CALL DTREVC( SIDE, 'B', SELECT, N, A, LDA, VL, LDVL, VR, LDVR,
$                N, NOUT, WORK( IWRK ), IERR )
END IF
*
IF( WANTVL ) THEN
*
*        Undo balancing of left eigenvectors
*        (Workspace: need N)
*
   CALL DGEBAK( 'B', 'L', N, ILO, IHI, WORK( IBAL ), N, VL, LDVL,
$                IERR )
*
*        Normalize left eigenvectors and make largest component real
*
   DO 20 I = 1, N
      IF( WI( I ).EQ.ZERO ) THEN
         SCL = ONE / DNRM2( N, VL( 1, I ), 1 )
         CALL DSCAL( N, SCL, VL( 1, I ), 1 )
      ELSE IF( WI( I ).GT.ZERO ) THEN
         SCL = ONE / DLAPY2( DNRM2( N, VL( 1, I ), 1 ),
$               DNRM2( N, VL( 1, I+1 ), 1 ) )
         CALL DSCAL( N, SCL, VL( 1, I ), 1 )
         CALL DSCAL( N, SCL, VL( 1, I+1 ), 1 )
         DO 10 K = 1, N
            WORK( IWRK+K-1 ) = VL( K, I )**2 + VL( K, I+1 )**2
10          CONTINUE
         K = IDAMAX( N, WORK( IWRK ), 1 )
         CALL DLARTG( VL( K, I ), VL( K, I+1 ), CS, SN, R )
         CALL DROT( N, VL( 1, I ), 1, VL( 1, I+1 ), 1, CS, SN )
         VL( K, I+1 ) = ZERO
      END IF
20    CONTINUE
END IF
*
IF( WANTVR ) THEN
*
*        Undo balancing of right eigenvectors
*        (Workspace: need N)
*
   CALL DGEBAK( 'B', 'R', N, ILO, IHI, WORK( IBAL ), N, VR, LDVR,
$                IERR )
*
*        Normalize right eigenvectors and make largest component real
*
   DO 40 I = 1, N
      IF( WI( I ).EQ.ZERO ) THEN
         SCL = ONE / DNRM2( N, VR( 1, I ), 1 )
         CALL DSCAL( N, SCL, VR( 1, I ), 1 )
      ELSE IF( WI( I ).GT.ZERO ) THEN
         SCL = ONE / DLAPY2( DNRM2( N, VR( 1, I ), 1 ),
$               DNRM2( N, VR( 1, I+1 ), 1 ) )
         CALL DSCAL( N, SCL, VR( 1, I ), 1 )
         CALL DSCAL( N, SCL, VR( 1, I+1 ), 1 )
         DO 30 K = 1, N
            WORK( IWRK+K-1 ) = VR( K, I )**2 + VR( K, I+1 )**2
30          CONTINUE
         K = IDAMAX( N, WORK( IWRK ), 1 )
         CALL DLARTG( VR( K, I ), VR( K, I+1 ), CS, SN, R )
         CALL DROT( N, VR( 1, I ), 1, VR( 1, I+1 ), 1, CS, SN )
         VR( K, I+1 ) = ZERO
      END IF
40    CONTINUE
END IF
*
*     Undo scaling if necessary
*
50 CONTINUE
IF( SCALEA ) THEN
   CALL DLASCL( 'G', 0, 0, CSCALE, ANRM, N-INFO, 1, WR( INFO+1 ),
$                MAX( N-INFO, 1 ), IERR )
   CALL DLASCL( 'G', 0, 0, CSCALE, ANRM, N-INFO, 1, WI( INFO+1 ),
$                MAX( N-INFO, 1 ), IERR )
   IF( INFO.GT.0 ) THEN
      CALL DLASCL( 'G', 0, 0, CSCALE, ANRM, ILO-1, 1, WR, N,
$                   IERR )
      CALL DLASCL( 'G', 0, 0, CSCALE, ANRM, ILO-1, 1, WI, N,
$                   IERR )
   END IF
END IF
*
WORK( 1 ) = MAXWRK
RETURN
*
*     End of DGEEV
*
END
```

Maybe it well help you as all the keywords are to find there (Schur, QR, and co.).

I highly recommend to check out *Desire's* link too (above comment) which looks really nice (and [here some table of SVD-algs within](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node32.html))!