# index of eigenvalues returned by numpy.linalg.eigvals - how to track the algorithm used?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, lapack, eigenvalue

I have a python script that calls `numpy.linalg.eigvals(A)`, and goes on to find the eigenvalue of matrix `A` with the largest imaginary part; call this `lambda_k`.

I track the index `k` of `lambda_k` as I change `A` slowly. I find that the index `k` flickers between around 5 different values, with a spread that is quite small compared to the size of `A` (e.g. a spread of 100 when `A` has 8192*8192 entries).

I know the order of eigenvalues carries no meaning, but as the entries of `A` vary slowly and continuously shouldn't there be a slow, continuous change in the eigenvalues and eigenvectors returned by the LAPACK solver that `eigvals` calls? And so shouldn't the order in which these are returned change continuously (and hence `k`)?

And is there a way of tracking which algorithm is being called by `eigvals`? So that I can check the algorithm's docs and spot if there is anything that maybe permutes `A` and hence change the order of eigenvalues.

Comment: The documentation says it uses `_geev` in LAPACK.  Beyond that, this isn't really a Python question. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigvals.html

Comment: *"And is there a way of tracking which algorithm is being called by eigvals"* Sure, low-level profilers can do that easily. On (bare-metal) Linux, there is `perf` and VTune (x86-64). On (bare-metal) Windows, VTune also works well. IDK for MacOS. Besides, the doc can help as proposed by FrankYellin. On top of that, you can check the code of Numpy or use a debugger like GDB on Linux or MSVC on Windows (this requires to build Numpy on your machine).

Comment: previous questions, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921108/how-does-scipy-linalg-eigvals-actually-calculate-eigenvalues, https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34134/how-to-know-which-lapacks-function-is-used-by-scipys-eig-function

Comment: If the eigenvalues are unordered, and complex, then the values will be 'scattered' in 2d space (real/imaginary).  'order' in that 2d space is poorly defined.  Magnitude might exibit a more consistent order.  It doesn't look like the python level (or even cython) determines the order; it's all internal to the LAPACK function(s).  I suspect you'll have to search in a more general math environment; python/scipy won't help.

Comment: Related question using Mathematica https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165167/tracking-eigenvalues-through-a-crossing